# Quality of scaled-down UILabels

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel, scaling

I'm using Swift 3 to create an iOS interface where some `UIView`s containing (amongst other things) `UILabel`s are scaled up and down based on where they're being positioned on the screen. My first approach was to create and populate the views at a comfortably large size (say 100x100) and then scale them as needed using `CGAffineTransform(scaleX:y:)`, however I've noticed that the downscaling of the text in the labels isn't graceful at all, and the text becomes pixelated and close to unreadable at small scales. As a comparison (see example below), changing the font size directly gives much better results, however the structure within my views is somewhat complex and having to redraw everything based on some size factor would be a hassle. Is there a better and smoother way to approach this problem?

Here's an example project I've created to illustrate the problem, as well as the output in the simulator (same as on the iPhone itself), downscaled views are on the left (red) and changed font sizes are the right (green).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        for i in 1...10 {
            let f = CGFloat(1.0) / CGFloat(i)
            let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))
            view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))
            label1.text = "\(100 / i)%"
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 24.0)
            label1.textAlignment = .right
            view1.addSubview(label1)
            view1.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: f, y: f)
            view1.center = CGPoint(x: 160 - 75.0 * f, y: CGFloat(60 * i) + 25.0 * f)
            self.view.addSubview(view1)

            let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(170), y: CGFloat(60 * i), width: 150 * f, height: 50 * f))
            view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150 * f, height: 50 * f))
            label2.text = "\(100 / i)%"
            label2.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 24.0 * f)
            view2.addSubview(label2)
            self.view.addSubview(view2)

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image: downscaling the view vs. changing the font size]

Comment: where is autolayout?

Comment: I'm not using any autolayout in this example, it's hand-written code only

Comment: Do you need to scale the bounding-box to a specific size? Or the font? Can you use `.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` and let it auto-scale the font?

Comment: @DonMag I may be mistaken but I don't think that's the right approach. The text in the boxes is mostly static, it's the size of the complete view that changes, and it may change several times in the view's lifecycle. The way I understand it, `adjustFontSizeToFitWidth = true` may be used to change the text size when the text is too large for the bounding box, but it won't help when scaling down the view. I've tried adding it to my code, to no avail.

Comment: @David - If you set the label size to change with its "container view" size, perhaps it would work. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

This *might* be an answer - but not really suitable for a comment, so...

Give this a try - it creates a 3rd "column" of yellow-background views, using `.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`. The font size will auto-adjust based on the size of the views that contain the labels.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for i in 1...10 {
        let f = CGFloat(1.0) / CGFloat(i)
        let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))
        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))
        label1.text = "\(100 / i)%"
        label1.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 24.0)
        label1.textAlignment = .right
        view1.addSubview(label1)
        view1.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: f, y: f)
        view1.center = CGPoint(x: 160 - 75.0 * f, y: CGFloat(60 * i) + 25.0 * f)
        self.view.addSubview(view1)

        let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(170), y: CGFloat(60 * i), width: 150 * f, height: 50 * f))
        view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        let label2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150 * f, height: 50 * f))
        label2.text = "\(100 / i)%"
        label2.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 24.0 * f)
        view2.addSubview(label2)
        self.view.addSubview(view2)

        let view3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(270), y: CGFloat(60 * i), width: 150 * f, height: 50 * f))
        view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        let label3 = UILabel(frame: view3.bounds)
        label3.text = "\(100 / i)%"
        label3.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 24.0)
        label3.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label3.minimumScaleFactor = 0.05
        label3.numberOfLines = 0
        // we want the label to resize with the view, if the view frame changes
        label3.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view3.autoresizesSubviews = true
        view3.addSubview(label3)
        self.view.addSubview(view3)

    }
}
```

Comment: That's definitely an improvement, thanks! The only little thing is that the ratio between the size of the text and the size of the outer frame changes because the size of the text is constrained by the frame's bounds, it doesn't actually "scale". So I guess I'll just have to enclose my `UILabel`s within tight-fitting `UIView`s to use that technique. In my app, I have several pieces of text that all have to scale together with respect to the size of the outer view, I'll need some intermediary layers

Comment: I was able to reproduce almost exactly the original result while keeping the high quality and not changing the font size by hand, by using this technique and enclosing the `UILabel` in an intermediary `UIView`, whose height I then had to tweak (font size * 1.25) to account for the space around the text. There may be a better/easier way to do it but at least this one works and looks good.

Comment: @David - There is (almost) always more than one way of doing things... glad you got the results you wanted.